# Unable to retrieve attributes from Portlet Session which set in HttpSession

Tags: session, servlets, portlet, websphere-portal

I am trying to implement some captcha function, "`/UP2/servlet/captch`" is pointing to a servlet, which will generate a random captcha and store it in `HttpSession`, and I want to retrieve this later in WebSphere Portal custom portlet.

Here is my captcha image:

```
<img src="/UP2/servlet/captch" id="captch"/>
```

Here is servlet to generate captcha String and store in `HttpSession`

```
  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
                //...
                request.getSession().setAttribute("key", capstr);
                //...
    }
```

When I submit the portlet, I want to retrieve the "key" from session, I use below code to retrieve:(The `request` here is `PortletRequest`(`ActionRequest`))

```
Object jCaptchainput = PortletUtils.getHttpServletRequest(request).getSession().getAttribute("key");
```

but I always get `null`
This also not working:

```
Object jCaptchainput = request.getPortletSession().getAttribute("key", PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
```

Can anyone help me out? Really want to know how to communicate between `Servlet` and `Portlet` in WebSphere Portal. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this for an authenticated users or unathenticated users?  if unathenticated do you have anonymous sessions enabled?  I believe you may be running into the below, you can also set it globally via Navigator service with public.session set to true http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYJ99_8.0.0/admin/srvcfgref_navigator.html

*In this case, a temporary session is created and your session information will be lost in the next request. If you need to enable session tracking across requests for non-authenticated users, you can do so by setting the public.session parameter in the portal Navigator service configuration or by setting the com.ibm.portal.public.session container run time option in a JSR 286 portlet deployment descriptor. Note that this may result in significantly increased memory consumption. For details about the com.ibm.portal.public.session option and a code sample refer to the topic about Deployment descriptors, section about Container run time options. Instead of using these options, portlets that need to maintain interaction state even for non-authenticated users should use render parameters to keep this information instead of the portlet session, as recommended by the Java Portlet Specification.*